# Can you identify the design of these chess pieces?

Tags: pieces, identify-this

I was wondering if anyone could identify the name of this chess piece design, or possibly the name of its designer? It's obviously not the standard Staunton set.

[image: White pieces]
[image: Black pieces]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not exact match, the style of your set aligns with what is called the St. George style. Compare your set to this image from the [Staunton chess set Wikipedia.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staunton_chess_set#/media/File%3AChess_set_4o06.jpg) An [article](http://www.chess-museum.com/st-george-chessmen.html) on chess-museum.com provides more information about this style.

[image]

In comparison to your image, the kings, bishops, queens and pawns builds are extremely similar. The rooks and knights are not exact nor are the dimensions the same. I suspect that you have either a variation or a modernized design of the St. George style. Perhaps it is a mesh with the Staunton style.

Comment: Ah, yes, that certainly seems to be the general style. I'm hoping soneone can narrow it down somewhat more. This set is at least 40 years old, by the way.